# Sweet Alert2 - Confirm delete (NodeJS/Express/Mongoose/MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, sweetalert2

Currently in my NodeJS app I have an inline confirmation to delete a record:

```
<form id="btn-form" action="/thought/<%- thought._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this thought post?');">
    <button class="btn-none trash-index-page"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
</form>
```

I would like to use Sweet Alert2 for the 'are you sure' popup message; so far I have this, though I'm unsure how to translate the inline method DELETE/POST to the Sweet Alert result.isConfirmed function

```
<form id="btn-form" action="/thought/<%- thought._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST" onclick="ConfirmDelete()">
    <button class="btn-none trash-index-page"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
</form> 


    function ConfirmDelete() {
        return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this record?');
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure you wish to delete this record?',
            showDenyButton: true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
            denyButtonText: 'No',
        }).then((result) => {
        /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                Swal.fire('Record deleted!', '', 'success')
            } else if (result.isDenied) {
                Swal.fire('Record not deleted', '', 'info')
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call javascript `fetch` inside the sweetalert if user confirmed

```js
fetch(`URL`, {method: "DELETE",})
```